# Turn series into numpy array and concatenate it with array of diferent dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have an array `x_train` with the following shape (3800, 10):

```
[[ 8.58786106  2.05531597 47.69544082 ... 22.18313066 58.95737578
  16.74565073]
 [ 9.12246609  2.22890568 54.10625074 ... 26.04059537 56.0996469
  18.67649081]
 [ 8.69304657  1.68278122 49.72647589 ... 27.39661295 55.67941362
  21.72374764]
 ...
 [ 7.38825607  1.9323082  42.25193966 ... 26.32971473 76.62631333
  23.39134685]
 [ 9.36668968  2.21513939 51.51743298 ... 15.17773412 48.62399762
  18.85870167]
 [ 6.85041714  1.48223543 48.24985089 ... 50.06416883 96.68290317
  45.1459154 ]]
```

and I need to concatenate the array above with an array extracted from this series (y_train):

```
0       1.0
1       0.0
2       1.0
3      -1.0
4      -1.0
       ... 
3795    0.0
3796   -1.0
3797    1.0
3798   -1.0
3799   -1.0
```

---

How do I format this series as an array and concatenate them in the following fashion?

```
xy_train_model = np.concatenate([x_train, y_train], axis=1)
```

so I end up with (3800, 11) shape:

```
[[ 8.58786106  2.05531597 47.69544082 ... 22.18313066 58.95737578
  16.74565073, 1.0]
 [ 9.12246609  2.22890568 54.10625074 ... 26.04059537 56.0996469
  18.67649081, 0.0]
 ...
```

Comment: How did you obtain y_train? Is it potentially a pandas series?

Comment: Yep pandas series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# the `None` is to broadcast it to (3800, 1) shape
y_train = series.to_numpy()[:,None]
```

And then your concatenation code will work. You could also use `np.hstack([x_train, y_train])`.

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is first make a DataFrame of x_train using `pandas.DataFrame` then make a new column and add y_train. Later if you want you can convert it into an array.